Optional parameter type inference
I'm struggling to find how to obtain a correct type inference when the parameter is optional:
function foo<T>(param: T) {
  return param;
}

const a = foo(null); // works: a is inferred as being `null`
const b = foo("bar"); // works: b is inferred as being the constant string "bar"
const c = foo("bar" as string); // works: c is inferred as being `string`
const d = foo(); // error: we need to pass a parameter
const e = foo(undefined); // works: e is inferred as being `undefined`, but it does not feel right

But if I make the parameter optional to handle the d case:
function foo<T>(param?: T) {
  return param;
}

const a = foo(null); // breaks: a is inferred as being `null | undefined`
const b = foo("bar"); // breaks: b is inferred as being the constant string "bar" or `undefined`
const c = foo("bar" as string); // breaks: c is inferred as being `string | undefined`
const d = foo(); // works: d is inferred as being `undefined`

I tried with param = undefined but it fails with 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.
I fail to find a way to make that parameter optional and avoid having the undefined unionized type inferred when a parameter is given.

seems work as expected in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgA4CGATgQLYD8AXIhgJSIDeAUIokQKZQhFKEmkBuJgF8mTCAgDOURAUQBeZKhxgQAGzW0BiAPQ7EAIw4EA1pOpyYkxDDDB2RDgBNZ1g+1sBzRAANVGxAAfRHAndmBbdicfcSkZAwUlOBwAIgNiFK1dfSN2U3NDG2tbe0co10MPMG8oAAt2RAkwaQIwGWkiL0Q0jMQ4Il9Q8Mjo2OaZCESUZJ6iFIqOryy9Q2MzakmrGzsHZwr3Lp9F6qCQsDCIsCiYpulEF0VpnGX9AHd+9fui7dK9gjcqt4fENLtcxGNJHA1OwAHRqOCeHAELQQqGw+GIgwo25ouEInAQbFSXEYnBOLRAA  what is your version of typescript ?

I don't think it's possible, when a parameter is optional, the undefined unionized type is automatically inferred.

@jeremy-denis it works as expected at runtime, the issue is that types are not inferred correctly (but typescript 5.4.5 since you asked)

@ArnaudFlaesch for now I removes the optionnality of the param and call with undefined when I have nothing to give, but if the function was in javascript and typed with typescript declaration, I'm almost sure we could create two declarations for the two "versions" of the function

I think you can use function overloads here, like this:
function foo(): undefined;
function foo<T>(param: T): T;
function foo<T>(param?: T): T | undefined {
  return param;
}

In this case you can receive more strict types of a - null, b - "bar", c - string, d - undefined
Btw, as @pilchard mentioned in the comment, it's possible to achieve the same result with only one overload:
function foo<T = undefined>(param?: T): T
function foo<T>(param: T) {
  return param;
}


you only need one overload (playground): function foo<T = undefined>(param?: T): T

Yeah I forgot how to do function overload properly... thank you !

You could make it as follows:
function foo<T>(param?: T | null) {
  return param;
}


With your code const a = foo("bar") infers the type of a to "bar" | null | undefined, and I'm trying to remove the incorrect types (null | undefined in this example)
